# BinaryTree implementation in java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I have this code for BinaryTree creation and traversal

```
class Node
{
    Integer data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node()
    {
        data = null;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
class BinaryTree
{
    Node head;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    BinaryTree()
    {
        head = null;
    }
    public void createNode(Node temp, Integer value) 
    {
        Node newnode= new Node();
        value = getData();
        newnode.data = value;
        temp = newnode;
        if(head==null)
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        System.out.println("If left child exits for ("+value+") enter y else n");
        if(input.next().charAt(0)=='y')
        {
            createNode(temp.left, value);
        }
        System.out.println("If right child exits for ("+value+") enter y else n");
        if(input.next().charAt(0)=='y')
        {
            createNode(temp.right, value);
        }       
    }
    public Integer getData()
    {
        out.println("Enter the value to insert:");
        return (Integer)input.nextInt();
    }

    public void print()
    {
        inorder(head);
    }
    public void inorder(Node node)
    {
        if(node!=null)
        {
            inorder(node.left);
            System.out.println(node.data);
            inorder(node.right);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}

class BinaryTreeWorker
{
    static BinaryTree treeObj = null;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void displaymenu()
    {
        int choice;
        do{
            out.print("\n Basic operations on a tree:");
            out.print("\n 1. Create tree  \n 2. Insert \n 3. Search value \n 4. print list\n Else. Exit \n Choice:");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    treeObj = createBTree();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    treeObj.createNode(null, null);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //searchnode();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    treeObj.print();
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }       
        }while(true);
    }
    public static BinaryTree createBTree()
    {
        return new BinaryTree();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        displaymenu();
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs. But I think there is something wrong with the inorder traversal.

I created the below tree,

```
    2
1       3
```

But it prints only 2.

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong with it?  Does it produce incorrect output?  What was expected?  What did you actually get?

Comment: FYI it's a very bad habit to mix user interface (especially blocking modal calls) with your domain object logic.  I would look into separating that logic out; it will make things much easier to debug.  Start by looking into the Model View Controller (MVC) paradigm.

Comment: another coding style comment: `inorder` does not require an instance of `Node` to run, make it static! [or even better: make it accept no args, and use `this` instead of passing `Node` as an argument]

Comment: it's not homework, but i was doing it for self-study. I have added the output to the original post

Comment: I still couldn't figure out what is wrong with createNode method!!

Comment: @SayemAhmed : I rarely log in to Stack overflow and really want to know that how does it matters if question is a homework or classwork or asked simply for self study? Though In any case I tried solving the problem and answered it.

Comment: Consider posting questions like this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have tried solving the problem your way and I have pasted the solution below.. Though I haven't tested it thoroughly so it might fail in some edge condition.. But I have tested it for one case. Kindly let me know if it fails in some scenario. I would appreciate others help in making this answer better. I agree that this solution is not the most ideal way to code a Binary Tree but it wont hurt this way if some one is just practicing..

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class Node
{
    Integer data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node()
    {
        data = null;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
class BinaryTree
{
    Node head;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    BinaryTree()
    {
        head = null;
    }

    public void createNode(Node temp,Node newnode) 
    {

        if(head==null)
        {
            System.out.println("No value exist in tree, the value just entered is set to Root");
            head = newnode;
            return;
        }
        if(temp==null)
            temp = head;

        System.out.println("where you want to insert this value, l for left of ("+temp.data+") ,r for right of ("+temp.data+")");
        char inputValue=input.next().charAt(0); 
        if(inputValue=='l'){
            if(temp.left==null)
            {
                temp.left=newnode;
                System.out.println("value got successfully added to left of ("+temp.data+")");
                return;
            }else  {
                System.out.println("value left to ("+temp.data+") is occupied 1by ("+temp.left.data+")");
                createNode(temp.left,newnode);
            }
        }
        else if(inputValue=='r')
        {
            if(temp.right==null)
            {
                temp.right=newnode;
                System.out.println("value got successfully added to right of ("+temp.data+")");
                return;

            }else  {
                System.out.println("value right to ("+temp.data+") is occupied by ("+temp.right.data+")");
                createNode(temp.right,newnode);
            }

        }else{
            System.out.println("incorrect input plz try again , correctly");
            return;
        }

    }
    public Node generateTree(){
        int [] a = new int[10];
        int index = 0; 
        while(index<a.length){
            a[index]=getData();
            index++;
        }
        if(a.length==0 ){
            return null;
        }
        Node newnode= new Node();
        /*newnode.left=null;
        newnode.right=null;*/
        return generateTreeWithArray(newnode,a,0);

    }
    public Node generateTreeWithArray(Node head,int [] a,int index){

        if(index >= a.length)
            return null;
        System.out.println("at index "+index+" value is "+a[index]);
        if(head==null)
            head= new Node();
        head.data = a[index];
        head.left=generateTreeWithArray(head.left,a,index*2+1);
        head.right=generateTreeWithArray(head.right,a,index*2+2);
        return head;
    }

    public Integer getData()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the value to insert:");
        return (Integer)input.nextInt();
    }

    public void print()
    {
        inorder(head);
    }
    public void inorder(Node node)
    {
        if(node!=null)
        {
            inorder(node.left);
            System.out.println(node.data);
            inorder(node.right);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}

public class BinaryTreeWorker
{
    static BinaryTree treeObj = null;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void displaymenu()
    {
        int choice;
        do{
            System.out.print("\n Basic operations on a tree:");
            System.out.print("\n 1. Create tree  \n 2. Insert \n 3. Search value \n 4. print list\n 5. generate a tree \n Else. Exit \n Choice:");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    treeObj = createBTree();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Node newnode= new Node();
                    newnode.data = getData();
                    newnode.left=null;
                    newnode.right=null;
                    treeObj.createNode(treeObj.head,newnode);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //searchnode();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("inorder traversal of list gives follows");
                    treeObj.print();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Node tempHead = treeObj.generateTree();
                    System.out.println("inorder traversal of list with head = ("+tempHead.data+")gives follows");
                    treeObj.inorder(tempHead);
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }       
        }while(true);
    }
    public static Integer getData()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the value to insert:");
        return (Integer)input.nextInt();
    }
    public static BinaryTree createBTree()
    {
        return new BinaryTree();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        displaymenu();
    }
}
```

**[Update]** : Updated the code to generate a binary tree using an array. This will involve less user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to implement Binary Tree in Java with all the traverse types and test cases as below

```
package com.nitin.tree;

public class Tree
{
    private Node parent;

    private int  data;

    private int  size = 0;

    public Tree() {
        parent = new Node(data);
    }

    public void add(int data) {

        if (size == 0) {
            parent.data = data;
            size++;
        } else {
            add(parent, new Node(data));
        }
    }

    private void add(Node root, Node newNode) {

        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (newNode.data < root.data) {

            if (root.left == null) {
                root.left = newNode;
                size++;
            } else {
                add(root.left, newNode);
            }
        } else {

            if (root.right == null) {
                root.right = newNode;
                size++;
            } else {
                add(root.right, newNode);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getLow() {

        Node current = parent;

        while (current.left != null) {
            current = current.left;
        }

        return current.data;
    }

    public int getHigh() {

        Node current = parent;

        while (current.right != null) {
            current = current.right;
        }

        return current.data;
    }

    private void in(Node node) {

        if (node != null) {

            in(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            in(node.right);
        }
    }

    private void pre(Node node) {

        if (node != null) {

            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            pre(node.left);
            pre(node.right);
        }
    }

    private void post(Node node) {

        if (node != null) {

            post(node.left);
            post(node.right);
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        }
    }

    public void preorder() {

        System.out.print("Preorder Traversal->");
        pre(parent);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void postorder() {

        System.out.print("Postorder Traversal->");
        post(parent);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void inorder() {

        System.out.print("Inorder Traversal->");
        in(parent);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private class Node {

        Node left;

        Node right;

        int  data;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {

        Node current = parent;
        System.out.print("Traverse From Left ");

        while (current.left != null && current.right != null) {

            System.out.print(current.data + "->[" + current.left.data + " " + current.right.data + "] ");
            current = current.left;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Traverse From Right ");

        current = parent;

        while (current.left != null && current.right != null) {

            System.out.print(current.data + "->[" + current.left.data + " " + current.right.data + "] ");
            current = current.right;
        }

        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String af[]) {

        Tree t = new Tree();

        t.add(40);
        t.add(25);
        t.add(78);
        t.add(10);
        t.add(32);
        t.add(50);
        t.add(93);
        t.add(3);
        t.add(17);
        t.add(30);
        t.add(38);

        System.out.println(t.getLow());

        System.out.println(t.getHigh());

        System.out.println("Size-" + t.size);

        System.out.println(t);

        t.inorder();

        t.preorder();

        t.postorder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `public void createNodes(Node temp, T data)` function. You pass in a parameter the same name as the class variable temp. First of all I don't think you need the class variable by itself. Second of all assigning to temp in this method has only local effect - you loose the information in the `temp` parameter, but setting temp, will not infuence its value in the called method. I suggest you rewrite the method so that it returns the pointer to the newly created node and assign this pointer to the `left` and `right` of the local `temp`. That way the changes will propagate out.

Answer (score 0):

another type of outputting the tree:

```
public void inorder() 
{
 inorder(root);
}

protected void visit(BSTNode<T> p) 
{
 System.out.println("Node: " + p.el + "Left Side:" + (p.left!=null?p.left.el:"null") +  
 "Right          Side:" + (p.right!=null?p.right.el:"null"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the BinaryTree Class as below. See the change on the the *createNode* method in particular.

The problem, as mentioned in the post before this, is that your reference doesn't persist when it is passed as an argument to the *createNode* method. That change is only local. You need to return an explicit Node reference in the method itself as you're creating the node.

```
public Node createNode() 
{

    Integer value = getData();


    Node temp = new Node(value);
    if(head==null)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    System.out.println("Do you want to add left branch on node("+value+")? Enter y/n");
    if(input.next().charAt(0)=='y')
    {
        temp.left=createNode();
    }
    System.out.println("Do you want to add right branch on node("+value+")? Enter y/n");
    if(input.next().charAt(0)=='y')
    {
        temp.right=createNode();
    }     

    return temp;
}
```

Here is the resulting output:

```
 Basic operations on a tree:
 1. Create tree  
 2. Insert 
 3. Search value 
 4. print list
 Else. Exit 
 Choice:1

 Basic operations on a tree:
 1. Create tree  
 2. Insert 
 3. Search value 
 4. print list
 Else. Exit 
 Choice:2
Enter the value to insert:
10
Do you want to add left branch on node(10)? Enter y/n
y
Enter the value to insert:
20
Do you want to add left branch on node(20)? Enter y/n
n
Do you want to add right branch on node(20)? Enter y/n
n
Do you want to add right branch on node(10)? Enter y/n
y
Enter the value to insert:
30
Do you want to add left branch on node(30)? Enter y/n
n
Do you want to add right branch on node(30)? Enter y/n
n

 Basic operations on a tree:
 1. Create tree  
 2. Insert 
 3. Search value 
 4. print list
 Else. Exit 
 Choice:4
20
10
30
```

I hope this will be of some help to someone later (even if this is 3 years late..). I just started learning about Binary Trees today myself. I'm actually planning on using this as a base to doing more involved tasks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the createNode method so that it works:

```
public Node createNode(Node temp, Integer value) 
{
    Node newnode = new Node();
    value = getData();
    newnode.data = value;
    temp = newnode;
    if(head == null)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    System.out.println("If left child exits for ("+value+") enter y else n");
    if(input.next().charAt(0) == 'y')
    {
        newnode.left = createNode(newnode.left, value);
    }
    System.out.println("If right child exits for ("+value+") enter y else n");
    if(input.next().charAt(0) == 'y')
    {
        newnode.right = createNode(newnode.right, value);
    } 
    return newnode;
}
```