# How to define a node class for multiple tree nodes that have 4 values assigned to it?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I am extremely new to java, and all my other searches lead to something more complex than my given question so I was wondering how i may go about this? i would like for my tree nodes to have consist of the following fields: parent, left, right and data.

Comment: Only one statement is related to question. Please add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to Java the most basic structure would be like this:

```
public class Node {
    private Node parent, left, right;
    private Integer data;

    public Node(Node parent, Node left, Node right, Integer data) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getParent() { return this.parent; }
    public Node getLeft() { return this.left; }
    public Node getRight() { return this.right; }
    public Integer getData() { return this.data; }

    public void setParent(Node parent) { this.parent = parent; }
    public void setLeft(Node left) { this.left = left; }
    public void setRight(Node right) { this.right = right; }
    public void setData(Integer data) { this.data = data; }
}
```

If you want to take it one step further and learn more about Object-Oriented Programming I would look into [generics.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private Node parent, left, right;
    private T data;

    // Getters, setters, compare methods here
}
```

This will let you declare a `Node<Integer>`, `Node<String>`, `Node<CustomClass>` to let you not be restricted to a certain type of data. You'll want to do `extend Comparable<T>` so that you can easily compare objects when doing an `insert()`, and other Tree functions.

Comment: to make multiple tree nodes, I'd just have to write this up again with a different node name after that bit of code above? eg. node 1?

Comment: If you want to make variables for those Nodes, then yes you would want to do something like `Node node1 = new Node(...), Node node2 = new Node(...)`, etc.

But since you're making a `BinaryTree` I would highly recommend you make `public class BinaryTree`, which will hold your root Node (which then points to more nodes), and having some methods for `insert, delete, search`.

Here's a link to an implementation of the full thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9955083/1327636