# Binary Tree in Java without using add method

Tags: java, oop, binary-tree

I've been trying to switch over to Java from Node and one thing I'm wondering about is how to construct a Binary Tree without putting a sorting algorithm in.  In Node, I could simply type the following:

```
function TreeNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = this.right = null;
}
let tree = new TreeNode(4);
tree.left = new TreeNode(2);
tree.left.left = new TreeNode(1);
```

What is the Java equivalent to this?  This is my current thought process

```
public class BinaryTree {
    private static TreeNode root;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        bt.TreeNode = ??

    }

  public class TreeNode {
      int val;
      TreeNode left;
      TreeNode right;
      TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BinaryTree implementation in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876406/binarytree-implementation-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

> @EJP: There is no need for two classes. Every tree node is a tree.
>
> OP: Can you show me this with one class.

Based on the code https://stackoverflow.com/a/50072165/139985 ....

```
public class BinaryTree {
    int data;
    BinaryTree left, right;

    public BinaryTree(int data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.left = this.right = null; // redundant ...
    }

    public int height() {
        height(this);
    }

    private int height(BinaryTree node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right)) + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(1);
        tree.left = new BinaryTree(2);
        tree.right = new BinaryTree(3);
        tree.left.right = new BinaryTree(4);

        System.out.println("The height of given binary tree is : " + tree.height());
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks doable. I'm not sure how can I delete the root node (node 1) and make the root as some other node (say 4)?

Comment: By assignment.  `BinaryTree root = ...;  root = newRoot;`  What we have here is an open data structure where operations are being performed by code outside of the *abstraction boundary*.  With this kind of API, there is no clear need to distinguish root nodes.  In fact, every node is a root node ... of a subtree.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Depends on the requirements what design to choose.

Comment: Well yes.  That applies to all data structures.

Comment: This is the first time probably I'm seeing the Binary tree with one class. Everywhere I read, pople tends to have a separate Node class.

Comment: how about a sheep wanting to be a lion? :P

Comment: So ... in the light of that, reflect on your previous comment: *"Everywhere I read ..."*.  My point is: 1) understand the issues for yourself, 2) make up your own mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your code something like this

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node left, right;

    public Node(int data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }

}

public class BinaryTree {
    Node root;

    public int height(Node node) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        return Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right)) + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        tree.root = new Node(1);
        tree.root.left = new Node(2);
        tree.root.right = new Node(3);
        tree.root.left.right = new Node(4);

        System.out.println("The height of given binary tree is : " + tree.height(tree.root));
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no need for two classes. Every tree node is a tree.

Comment: But still with two classes instead of one.