# Flattenned data into list of trees in java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have a data in tabular format like below:

```
Activity   | ActivityID | ParentID   
a1         | 1          |         
a2         | 2          | 1       
a3         | 3          |         
a4         | 4          | 3       
a5         | 5          | 2
a6         | 6          | 3
a7         | 7          | 1
```

I want to represent it like below in java:

```
a1 -> a2 -> a5   
   -> a7   
a3 -> a4  
   -> a6
```

Basically, a List of tree objects where a1 and a3 are roots of the tree having 2 children (a2, a7 and a4, a6 respectively) and a2 has one child (a5). The tree might no necessarily be binary and the data set can be big where one parent can have 50-100 children.

What would be the most effective way in Java ?

Comment: I'd recommend you to try something, and then improve if you are not satisfied :) After you have a first solution, you could ask how to improve this part or this part based on your research.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what code you have now? At least, show how  you represent these data in a program: are they objects or arrays or lists - this will determine what is the "path of least resistance" for the changes you need to make

Comment: Do you want the algorithm, or the code, what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

For a list of the tree, you can store your data in a structure like this:

```
final class Node{
  final int id;
  final string name;
  final List<Node> children;
}
```

So, the final structure is: `List<Node>`

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you search for is called **N-ary tree data structure** (you can refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ary_tree) and [nist](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/karyTree.html)).

If you are familiar with the binary tree (only two childs) , it will be easy for you to change fo n-ary tree (n childs).

In your case you have a forest of the n-ary tree (a list of the n-ary tree) , or you can consider it as one big tree with a common root, where all your effective tree begin at the level one.

The simplest way is to create a `Node{info, listChildren}` with a field info and a list (arrayList maybe) that will contain children, and a `NTreeClasse` that contain methods as addChild...generally we use a recursive function that check a certain condition to choose the right path where to insert a new node.

An example of implementing [N-ary tree source code](https://github.com/vivin/GenericTree)  and [binary tree source code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876406/binarytree-implementation-in-java)

If you want to improve your implementation or you seek optimisation, you have to consider some others points like:

- The type of the list of children in each node, which is related to the possible number of children, if the number is small we can use a simple array, if the number is big we can use hash table ... etc
- Is your tree change or not (dynamic with insert and delete)
- The traversal of the tree
- Avoid recursion: replace the recursive method by an iterative.
- Consider the construction steps, the normal way is for each element, we begin from the root, and we find the right path til we arrive to the leaf where we should insert the node (new child), you can maybe insert the children directly in the right place, its depend on your data and how you want to organize your tree.
- you can consider using array to store the tree, also depend strongly on your data.

Hope this helps a little bit to begin and to dig further.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you a short and straight forward algorithm. It's the dirty version. You can rewrite it as you wish(by which, i mean a better version):

I am assuming, there is a **table** array such that **table[i].activityID** would give me *ith* activity's id and **table[i].parentID** would give me the activity's *parent id* ans so on...

[Note: one more point here, I'm also assuming if there is no parent of an element then, its parent id is -1, i.e. in the given example of yours **a1's and a3's parent id would be -1**. This way we can understand which activity does not have any parent. If you have a better idea, you can use that].

Let us first define the **class Activity**

```
class Activity implements Comparable<Activity> {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Activity> children;
        
    Activity(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }
        
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Activity activity) {
        return this.id - activity.id;  
    }
}
```

As the activity class is defined, we'll be creating activity's now and put them in a TreeMap(just to keep track of them).

Notice, which activity's parent id is -1, those will be **roots** of trees [and according to your example, there could be several trees formed from your table]. We'll keep track of roots while creating activity's.

```
// to keep track of all acticities
TreeMap<int, Activity> activities = new TreeMap<>();

for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
    Activity a = new Activity(table[i].activityID, table[i].activityName);
    activities.add(a);
}

// to keep track of root activities
List<Activity> roots  = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
    // check if there is a parent of this Activity
    Activity activity = activities.get(table[i].activityID);

    // now, if activity has a parent
    // then, add activity in the parent's children list
    if(table[i].parentID != -1) {
        Activity parent = activities.get(table[i].parentID);

        // this is very bad way of writing code
        // just do it for now
        // later rewrite it
        parent.children.add(activity);

    } else {
        // and activity does not have a parent
        // then, it is a root
        roots.add(activity);
    }
}
```

Now, we're going to create a traverse method, which will help to traverse the tree node in order.

```
void traverse(Activity u) {
    System.out.println(u.name);
    
    for(Activity v: u.children) {
        traverse(v);
    }
}
```

Now, you can call this function using the root activities:

```
for(Activity rootActivity: roots) {
    traverse(rootActivity);
}
```

That's it...